# Multiple events are being fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

i have a simple script below that creates new html forms dynamically. When i attempt to submit one individually it submits the (this) clicked on form, and then submits all of the ones that came after it.

Really can't see what the bug is here (code):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function ($) {
$(function () {

    var addFormGroup = function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var $formGroup = $(this).closest('.form-group');
        var $multipleFormGroup = $formGroup.closest('.multiple-form-group');
        var $formGroupClone = $formGroup.clone();

        $(this)
            .toggleClass('btn-success btn-add btn-danger btn-remove')
            .html('–');

        $formGroupClone.find('input').val('');
        $formGroupClone.find('.concept').text('Phone');
        $formGroupClone.insertAfter($formGroup);

        var $lastFormGroupLast = $multipleFormGroup.find('.form-group:last');
        if ($multipleFormGroup.data('max') <= countFormGroup($multipleFormGroup)) {
            $lastFormGroupLast.find('.btn-add').attr('disabled', true);
        }

       $('form').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $( this ).serialize();
        var weburl = $(this).find(".web_url").val();
        var width = $(this).find(".width").val();//$('.width').val();
        var height = $(this).find(".height").val();//$('.height').val();
        var dee = <?php echo $deet[0]->id; ?>;
        $.post( "mde", { weburl: weburl, width: width, height: height, dee: dee })
          .done(function( data ) {
             u = data;
             alert(u);
          });
        //$.get(u);  
      });

    };

    var removeFormGroup = function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var $formGroup = $(this).closest('.form-group');
        var $multipleFormGroup = $formGroup.closest('.multiple-form-group');

        var $lastFormGroupLast = $multipleFormGroup.find('.form-group:last');
        if ($multipleFormGroup.data('max') >= countFormGroup($multipleFormGroup)) {
            $lastFormGroupLast.find('.btn-add').attr('disabled', false);
        }

        $formGroup.remove();
    };

    var selectFormGroup = function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var $selectGroup = $(this).closest('.input-group-select');
        var param = $(this).attr("href").replace("#","");
        var concept = $(this).text();

        $selectGroup.find('.concept').text(concept);
        $selectGroup.find('.input-group-select-val').val(param);

    }

    var countFormGroup = function ($form) {
        return $form.find('.form-group').length;
    };

    $(document).on('click', '.btn-add', addFormGroup);
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-remove', removeFormGroup);

});
})(jQuery);
</script>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      // Handler for .ready() called.
      $('form').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $( this ).serialize();
        var weburl = $(this).find(".web_url").val();
        var width = $(this).find(".width").val();//$('.width').val();
        var height = $(this).find(".height").val();//$('.height').val();
        var dee = <?php echo $deet[0]->id; ?>;
        $.post( "mde", { weburl: weburl, width: width, height: height, dee: dee })
          .done(function( data ) {
             u = data;
             alert(u);
          });
        //$.get(u);  
      });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: WHy the wrapping of the function in a function and mix of document.ready and $(function( ? - you assign TWO form submits. Remove the second script completely. Also every time you clone, you add another submit event

Comment: ah - my mistake, i had placed it in its own file. Just copied it here

Answer (score 0):

Something like this assuming the rest of the code works

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

    var addFormGroup = function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var $formGroup = $(this).closest('.form-group');
        var $multipleFormGroup = $formGroup.closest('.multiple-form-group');
        var $formGroupClone = $formGroup.clone();

        $(this)
            .toggleClass('btn-success btn-add btn-danger btn-remove')
            .html('–');

        $formGroupClone.find('input').val('');
        $formGroupClone.find('.concept').text('Phone');
        $formGroupClone.insertAfter($formGroup);

        var $lastFormGroupLast = $multipleFormGroup.find('.form-group:last');
        if ($multipleFormGroup.data('max') <= countFormGroup($multipleFormGroup)) {
            $lastFormGroupLast.find('.btn-add').attr('disabled', true);
        }           
    };

    var removeFormGroup = function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var $formGroup = $(this).closest('.form-group');
        var $multipleFormGroup = $formGroup.closest('.multiple-form-group');

        var $lastFormGroupLast = $multipleFormGroup.find('.form-group:last');
        if ($multipleFormGroup.data('max') >= countFormGroup($multipleFormGroup)) {
            $lastFormGroupLast.find('.btn-add').attr('disabled', false);
        }

        $formGroup.remove();
    };

    var selectFormGroup = function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var $selectGroup = $(this).closest('.input-group-select');
        var param = $(this).attr("href").replace("#","");
        var concept = $(this).text();

        $selectGroup.find('.concept').text(concept);
        $selectGroup.find('.input-group-select-val').val(param);

    }

    var countFormGroup = function ($form) {
        return $form.find('.form-group').length;
    };

    $(document).on('click', '.btn-add', addFormGroup);
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-remove', removeFormGroup);
    $(document).on('submit','form' function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        // $( this ).serialize(); // not used
        var weburl = $(this).find(".web_url").val();
        var width = $(this).find(".width").val();
        var height = $(this).find(".height").val();
        var dee = <?php echo $deet[0]->id; ?>;
        $.post( "mde", { weburl: weburl, width: width, height: height, dee: dee })
          .done(function( data ) {
             u = data;
             alert(u);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I've tested this for the last hour and it seems to work reasonably well. The one issue that remains is that on submit, the initial data is being continually resubmitted?

Comment: it resubmits whatever was submitted the first time on subsequent submits.

Comment: 1) you have serialise, why use the other stuff? 2) you have a hardcoded $deet[0]->id

Comment: Yes, commented serialize, that was there from before. The hard coded code is supposed to be on every submit so no issues there.

Comment: Here's a visual demo of what i am trying to do. When i click 'submit' here, the 'first form' is what gets submitted. http://recordit.co/yRWH0GAo5Q - or http://g.recordit.co/yRWH0GAo5Q.gif

Comment: Please post the actual html. Sounds like you submit the first form each time

Answer (score 0):

As they are dynamic elements use off() function along with on() function:

```
$('form').off().on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    ----
    ----
    ----

});
```

So that submit function will gets fired only on corresponding form.

Comment: I believe live() is now deprecated isn't it?

Comment: That depends on the jquery verion you have. Try it.

Comment: I have the most recent version - it is definitely deprecated.

Comment: Anyways, try it and check whether it is working for you.

Comment: There's no need to downvote this answer. This provides you clear idea to achieve solution for your issue. You need to change the deprecated function with updated one. That's it. I hope it will solve your issue.

Comment: If each form has its own submit button then there is no need to kill the event handler which might still be needed. I suspect the submit button is submitting the same form all the time